# Using NTLK properly with python

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to use python with NTLK to get a number of acronyms for a number of words (for now 2). It seems that I can get it to work with the first word, but not the second. I'm guessing I still have lots to learn about NTLK. There is some simplified example code below. I am basically trying to get two lists of acronyms, 1 list for each word. All was well with the first for loop. After I tried the second word I get:

```
syn2 = wn.synsets(word)[0].lemmas[y]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Hope someone can aid me in my understanding of why this is happening.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import string
from array import * 

syn1 = '' 
syn2 = '' 
mylist = []    
mylist2 = []    
mylist3 = []  


Web_Keywd = 'car loan'
wuser_words = Web_Keywd.split()   

for word in wuser_words:                           


     i=i+1
     #first
     if (i == 1) :
         synset1 = wn.synsets(word)    
         y = 0     
         for synset in synset1:
             syn1 = wn.synsets(word)[0].lemmas[y]
             syn1 = syn1.name
             mylist2.append(syn1)
             y=y+1
     if (i == 2) :
         y = 0     
         for synset2 in wn.synsets(word):
             syn2 = wn.synsets(word)[0].lemmas[y]
             syn2 = syn2.name
             mylist3.append(syn2)
             y=y+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've perhaps misleaded you in my previous answer with the use of `wn.synsets(word)[0].lemmas[y]`. You need to explicitly loop over the lemmas, as you can't know how many there are in advance. Example use case:

```
Web_Keywd = 'car loan cheap'

results = {}
for word in Web_Keywd.split():
    for synset in wn.synsets(word):
        for lemma in synset.lemmas:
            results.setdefault(word, []).append(lemma.name)
```

`results` now looks as follows:

```
{'car': ['car', 'auto', 'automobile', 'machine'...],
'loan': ['loan', 'loanword', 'loan', 'lend', 'loan'...],
'cheap': ['cheap', 'inexpensive', 'brassy', 'cheap...]}
```

To get unique results *for each word submitted, independently of the others*:

```
.... # same as above
            results.setdefault(word, set()).add(lemma.name)
```

To get a list of unique words for *all* the words submitted:

```
Web_Keywd = 'car loan cheap'

words = set(Web_Keywd.split())
results = set(
    lemma.name
    for word in words
        for synset in wn.synsets(word)
            for lemma in synset.lemmas
)
# results -> {'loanword', 'tatty', 'automobile', 'cheap', 'chinchy',...
```

Comment: Thanks this helps somewhat. When I move into a list wordlist.append(results.get("car"))  I notice the main word "car" seems to be repeated several times..is there a way around this?

Comment: Thanks this seems to be working (at least for the most part). I seem to get some unexpected results though, when I do a search for 'cat'. I get results like vomit, purge, guy, etc. I am not sure how these words are returned for cat. Also looking at an online thesaurus I see words returned like bobcat, kitty, etc which I would expect to see in the ntlk results(but are not). Wondering if you know why this is?